# C++ std::regex multiline

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, stl, std

Я работаю в `Visual Studio 19`. В настройках указал `C++17`.

Вообщем мне нужен флаг `multiline`, а его тупо нет. Я читал, что он есть с `C++17`. Но в `vs19` его нет.

Пишу вот так:
`std::regex::multiline` , вызывается ошибка, мол нету такой переменной.

Что мне делать?

Comment: Похоже, что он нигде не реализован

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На данный момент не существует реализаций, поддерживающих С++17 полностью

Ни clang, ни gcc, ни msvc не поддерживают std::regex multiline

Comment: Какая именно строка по ссылке говорит о фиче из вопроса?

Comment: 17 и 20 не перепутал? По 17 я вижу полностью зелёную колонку для VS за исключением одной ячейки: _"C++17 should refer to C11 instead of C99"._

Comment: И вообще, а как собственно это отвечает на вопрос?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, спутал стандарты, но тот факт, что он не поддерживается нигде я проверил на clang, gcc и msvc

Comment: А если я в строке все `\n` заменю на `\\n`, а потом после обработки обратно, будет же работать?

Comment: @Данил задайте новый вопрос. Если он по созданию регулярного выражения, то прочтите описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения] сначала